# How to combine a Bootstrap card (class="card") with Inline Checkboxes (class="form-check-inline"). It seems to not work properly

Tags: bootstrap-4

I tried to combine in Bootstrap 4 the class "card" with a form. The form contains two checkboxes. They should be display side by side (class "form-check-inline")

I used sample code from w3schools for setting up a form with inline checkboxes. Everything worked fine. Checkboxes showed up side by side as expected.
Then I encapsulated it in a card class. After that the checkboxes showed up one above the other

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Form control: inline checkbox</h2>
<p>The form below contains two inline checkboxes:</p>
<form action="/action_page.php">
<div class="card" style="margin-top:2%">
<div class="card-header">
Test
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">
<label class="form-check-label" for="check1">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check1" 
name="vehicle1" value="something" checked>Option 1
</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">
<label class="form-check-label" for="check2">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check2" 
name="vehicle2" value="something">Option 2
</label>
</div>
</div>      
</form>
</div>
```

Is this an issue of the card class or did I something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `card-body`...

```
      <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Test
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-check-inline">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="check1">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check1" name="vehicle1" value="something" checked="">Option 1
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check-inline">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="check2">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check2" name="vehicle2" value="something">Option 2
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/6CVUqA6mD3

The `card` class is `display:flex flex-direction:column` so putting content directly inside the card will layout vertically.